# How to Efficiently Find Object Attribute from a Group of Objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have just implemented a feature on my site which allows users to re-order the nav and then the custom positioning is saved to the database.

This part is fine but before I had created a model which inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`, e.g.

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
```

but to avoid creating a new table for every type of preference I've refactored it to inherit from `UserPreference`:

```
class MenuItem < UserPreference

class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
```

so in my `ApplicationController` I am doing the following:

```
before_filter :get_user_preferences

def get_user_preferences
  @user_preferences = UserPreference.find_all_by_user_id(@person.id)
  @menu_items = @user_preferences.select{|x| x.type == MenuItem}
end
```

Then at the moment in my partial which handles the nav I have the following:

```
<%= debug @menu_items %>
```

An example object is

```
- !ruby/object:MenuItem 
  attributes: 
    key: dashboard
    created_at: 2014-03-13 12:43:43 +00:00
    updated_at: 2014-03-13 12:43:43 +00:00
    user_id: 940
    id: 1
    value: "1"
    type: MenuItem
    attributes_cache: {}
```

So, the question is, is there a quick way I can select the object based on it's `key` attribute?

What I want to achieve is:

```
<li data-sort="<%= !value_attribute_from_object.blank? ? value_attribute_from_object : '1' %>" data-id="key_attribute_from_object">
```

so the resulting html would be

```
<li data-sort="1" data-id="dashboard">
```

Then I do the same for all my other sections.

The ways I've thought about doing it are simply setting individual variables for the `key` and `value` for every object but I'd rather do it a smarter way if possible so that I don't need to remember and update this part of the code if a new section is added (or even if a current section is removed).

Is there such a way or do I just need to bite the bullet?

Comment: What do you mean by select the object? Do you mean pick out an element from the menu_items with a specific key?

Comment: yes, sorry, couldn't quite find the best way to explain what I wanted.  So basically, get `key` and `value` from object where `key` is `dashboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean,

```
dashboard_value = @menu_items.select{|item| item.key == 'dashboard'}.map(&:value)
```

This will give you the value of the object with the key 'dashboard'

[EDIT]

If you have an array of values

```
 value_array = ['dashboard', 'another_item']
 kv_pairs = {}
 value_array.each do |val|
   kv_pairs[val] = @menu_items.select{|item| item.key == val}.map(&:value)
 end
```

Comment: yeah that does it perfectly, I assume there's no better way than creating a new variable for every value?, Ideally I'd like to do the check in-line but that might not be possible.